# [$injector:modulerr]Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

my problem is that Error: [$injector:nomod]Module'myApp' is not available!You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. ...

I make my project MVC logic. It is my main angular codes

```
"use strict";

var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

this is my angular controller codes

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','myFactory',function ($scope,userService) {
    var self=this;
    self.users=[];

    getAllData();

    function getAllData() {
        userService.getAllData()
            .then(function (value) {
                self.users=value;
            },function (reason) {
                console.log('Error');
            });
    }

}]);
```

and this is my angular service codes

```
app.factory('myFactory',['$http','$q',function ($http,$q) {
    var uri='href="localhost:8080/index"';
    var factory=
        {getAllData:getAllData};

    return factory;


    function getAllData() {
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        $http.get(uri)
            .then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },function (reason) {
                deferred.reject(reason);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

this is my html codes what i used in index.html

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="/static/userController.js"></script>
<script src="/static/angular/userService.js"></script>
```

and this is my Controller class maybe help you with something

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String home(){

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Please help me, why i got error? version is higher than 1.3 and script codes written correctly. I have looked internet what talking about script forgot

I added files photo

[image]

and this is code in html that i wanted to display my all users in the table

```
<tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="user in myCtrl.getAllData">
                <td ng-bind="user.id"></td>
                <td ng-bind="user.name"></td>
                <td ng-bind="user.surname"></td>
                <td ng-bind="user.phone"></td>
                <td ng-bind="user.age"></td>
                <td ng-bind="user.note"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
```

**Note**: It is not full of codes, just part of one

Comment: can you share your folder structure ?

Comment: I added. Please say something if it solve this problem

Comment: I don't think this would cause the error you're seeing, but your script reference to `userController` is `<script src="/static/userController.js"></script>` whereas it should be `<script src="/static/angular/userController.js"></script>`

Comment: no it didnt solved..

Comment: I added a part of html codes where i used to show data in the table

Comment: Any other errors in the console? Loading errors?

Answer (score 0):

By default spring boot looks for static files in static folder. So you no need to include 'static' in the path. Just reference like below.

```
<script src="angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="angular/userController.js"></script>
<script src="angular/userService.js"></script>
```

and I see you are loading angular and angular.min.js twice, it is not required , just load either of them only once. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not an integration issue. It's on the Angular side.

Comment: are you getting any errors in console ? Did you check in network tab - all your resources loading?, i tried with your code, it works fine for me. can you share your HTML code as well.  try removing only static string from the url's ?

Comment: console is fine - 2019-11-15 16:48:36.309  INFO 13580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-15 16:48:36.309  INFO 13580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-15 16:48:36.313  INFO 13580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms  i cleared all static string from my scripts but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

This type of issues happen when the dependency you are passing to the module/or controller is not matching with any of the defined services.

I see you are using `userService` in the function argument but, there is not definition to that, I believe you should use `myFactory` instead.

`app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','myFactory',function ($scope,myFactory) {`

Comment: app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','myFactory',function ($scope,myFactory) {
    var self=this;
    self.users=[];

    getAllData();
    
    function getAllData() {
        myFactory.getAllData()
            .then(function (value) {
                self.users=value;
            },function (reason) {
                console.log('Error');
            });
    }

}]);